# How to use OpenCV with GPU on Colab?

Tags: python, opencv, google-colaboratory, yolo, darknet

I am trying to make human detection using YOLOv4 on Colab. The code includes this lines:

```
import cv2

net =cv2.dnn.readNetFromDarknet(yolo_config_path,yolo_weights_path)

if cuda:
    net.setPreferableBackend(cv2.dnn.DNN_BACKEND_CUDA)
    net.setPreferableTarget(cv2.dnn.DNN_TARGET_CUDA)
```

However, if I run this cell directly on Colab, I encounter an error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run_yolo.py", line 26, in <module>
    net =cv2.dnn.readNetFromDarknet(yolo_config_path,yolo_weights_path)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.2) /io/opencv/modules/dnn/src/darknet/darknet_io.cpp:554: error: (-212:Parsing error) Unsupported activation: mish in function 'ReadDarknetFromCfgStream'
```

I run this cell to avoid the error:

```
%cd /content
!git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv
!git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib
!mkdir /content/build
%cd /content/build
!cmake -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/content/opencv_contrib/modules  -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF  -DBUILD_TESTS=OFF  -DBUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF -DBUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF -DWITH_OPENEXR=OFF -DWITH_CUDA=ON -DWITH_CUBLAS=ON -DWITH_CUDNN=ON -DOPENCV_DNN_CUDA=ON /content/opencv
!make -j8 install
```

When I write this line:

```
import cv2
cv2.__version__
```

The result is 4.5.1-dev.

But when I run the code, cv2 is OpenCV(4.1.2). How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Are you sure that you have only one opencv version installed your python environment? Maybe conflicting versions causes this. Yolov4 is not available for it. You might have to use version 3.4.12 or later or 4.4.0<=

Comment: I wrote this line: !pip install opencv-python==3.4.13.47. When I run the code again, it gave this error : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run_yolo.py", line 29, in <module>
    net.setPreferableBackend(cv2.dnn.DNN_BACKEND_CUDA)
AttributeError: module 'cv2.dnn' has no attribute 'DNN_BACKEND_CUDA'

Comment: Can you check `pip list` for  packages? I'm not familiar with how Google Colab handles dependencies but most probably it uses `4.1.2` by default. You need to uninstall it first then run your code(cell) above to install from source.

Comment: I checked the packages. opencv-python is 3.4.13.47 and opencv-contrib-python is 3.4.13.47. I think this version does not support dnn.

Comment: Alright that might cause the problem. Never install both packages! Just use `opencv-contrib-python` and as you said better to stick `4.4.x` or later for Yolov4

Comment: I changed the version to opencv-contrib-python 4.5.1.48 and opencv-python 4.5.1.48. It gave this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run_yolo.py", line 34, in <module>
    overlapping_threshold,write_output,show_display,labels)
  File "/content/drive/MyDrive/capstone_opencv/my_utils.py", line 39, in get_yolo_preds
    layerOutputs = net.forward(ln)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.1) /tmp/pip-req-build-1syr35c1/opencv/modules/dnn/src/dnn.cpp:1142: error: (-213:The function/feature is not implemented) Unknown backend identifier in function 'wrapMat'

Comment: you need to restart Runtime (Ctrl+M) after you run make install command.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following version of opencv if you are going to use Yolov4 or other stuff:

```
!pip install opencv-contrib-python==3.4.13.47 --force-reinstall
```